# Optimaze SQL Database table for multiple writes single read

Tags: sql-server, sql-optimization

I am developing a feature that will be used as processes progress monitor.

I will span 40-50 threads that might take several minutes or even hours to finish and they will update it's status to a datatable.

From the web app i will create a polling mechanism that will read the processes status using one read every 0.5 sec.

I need to optimize the table for multiple writes at a sec and one read per 0.5 sec. I don't care if I read a dirty state since it's just for monitoring the process, it's not that critical.

This is the table I am using

```
CREATE TABLE [cmn].[ProcessProgress]
(
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [status] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [step] [int] NOT NULL,
    [max_step] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProcessProgress] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [id] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY  = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) 
GO
```

And the select with `(NOLOCK)` I suppose I have to use

```
SELECT * FROM [cmn].[ProcessProgress] (NOLOCK)
```

Do I have to use a transaction with a special `ISOLATION LEVEL` or `(nolock)` is sufficient? Or `(nolock)` will make thinks worse?

Can you suggest what would be the most optimized solution for this problem?

Comment: i would add a datetime column as well; and over time you can partition this table to do even faster reads. Do you need to hold historic data or can you off-load it over time to another table (for reporting , historic purpose).

Comment: If it's really 40/50 tiny row writes/sec and 2 reads/sec (tops) then it's really not going to matter much what approach you use. Even the wimpiest of servers can pull a load like that at 95% idle, even if everything happened under `SERIALIZABLE`.

Comment: Are you trying to optimize for just the website or for the queue as well?

Comment: @JeroenMostert This 40 may grow to 400 or hopefully to 4000 one day so I want to make sure the table is ready to handle this load

Comment: @DanielN I want the 'queue', lets say WebJob, to Make fast writes without any deadlock and the web site to make reads without affecting the webjob's performance

Comment: @junketsu This table stays clean, only the active processes, when a process finishes it deletes the appropriate row from the table. I am not sure I understand about the partition of the table, does this make the index run faster?

Comment: @MenelaosVergis ; since your already stating your hoping for 4K rows over time; and you want read /write times under 1 sec. Partition that table.So you do not run into historic data. Also off hours rebuild stats, index(s) atleast Primary key index.

Comment: @junketsu I suppose 4k rows doesn't justify partitions, it's such a small amount of rows for a table. My problem is not storing 4k rows but it's 4k row writes in a sec and some reads, I suppose that the reads might grow a bit

Answer (score 1):

Just set the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option on your database, and the readers and writers will never conflict.  Instead they will use [Row Versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017):

```
alter database current set read_committed_snapshot on
```

In addition to increasing the concurrency and scalability of your application by eliminating blocking between readers and writers, it eliminates many deadlocks, and removes the incentive to perform dirty reads.

Comment: that's a huge hammer for a simple problem :)

Comment: No.  It should be the default for all new development.

Comment: This is great info! I was not aware of this option, I would have save my self from many headaches in the past. Instead of locking the rows on read it provide a snapshot of the data from the time the query begun. But, what is the catch? More memory consumption?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft can you please point to some official MS documentation that further explains or details why this should be the default option for new dev work.

Comment: Update/delete queries have to maintain the row versions so readers can see the "before" image of the rows, and rows require new 14 field to carry the row version pointer.

Comment: @DanielN the doc I linked explains the behavior and benefits.  And _in my opinion_ those benefits justify using RCSI is the default in all new OLTP development and moving to it in new versions of existing applications.

Comment: More information on the read_commited_snapshot: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5014/what-risks-are-there-if-we-enable-read-committed-snapshot-in-sql-server. Don't stay at the accepted answer, read the other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (hope id did not make too many mistakes). test code at the bottom is what would be executed by each thread.

```
if object_id('ProcessProgress') is not null
    drop table ProcessProgress
    Go

CREATE TABLE [ProcessProgress]
(
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), --added identity to shorten sample dev
    [status] [smallint] NOT NULL, --1 -ready,2-inprogress, 3-complete
    [step] [int] NOT NULL,
    [max_step] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProcessProgress] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [id] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY  = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) 
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO [ProcessProgress]
    (status, step, max_step)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1)
GO 1000

Go
IF OBJECT_ID('StartWork') is not null drop proc StartWork
GO
CREATE PROC StartWork
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

    BEGIN TRAN
        ;WITH TODO
        AS (
            SELECT TOP 1 Id, [status] from ProcessProgress WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) WHERE [status] = 1 --ready
        )
        UPDATE TODO 
            SET [status] = 2 --InProgress
        OUTPUT inserted.id 

    COMMIT
END
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('FinishWork') is not null drop proc FinishWork
GO
CREATE PROC FinishWork
    @id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
    BEGIN TRAN

    Update  ProcessProgress
        SET [Status] = 3 --finished
    WHERE
        id = @id

    COMMIT
END
GO


/*tester*/
declare @idout table (id int)
insert into @idout exec StartWork

declare @idin int = (Select top 1 id from @idout)
exec FinishWork @idin
```

Comment: You haven't explained what your code does. State the idea and how your implementation works this out.